# How do I find and open the most recent txt file within a subdirectory structure using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Using vb.net I am writing a standalone application that needs to read a value from the very latest text file written to a random subdirectory from a known directory. I need this to run on a scheduled basis so I am using the vb timer.
Despite searching the web for some time I can't seem to find any code to perform this relatively simple task without visual studio failing to compile all the examples I've tried. Surely this is quite a simple task?

Also what would be the most efficient way of doing this?

```
Private Sub tmrLoop_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrLoop.Tick

    For Each TXTFile As System.IO.FileInfo In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\10.179.221.125\cmsdata\GNH3D\TDD\TDD_waveradar\H1d3\"))
        .GetFileSystemInfos("*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTimeUTC)
        .Skip(PageSize * Page)
        .Take(PageSize)
        MsgBox(TXTFile)
    Next
End Sub
```

The above code doesn't like the Server.MapPath part

Comment: Take out the call to `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: That causes another error - Expression is of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo', which is not a collection type????

Comment: For the record, `Server.MapPath` is for ASP.NET when you want to map a relative or virtual path to an absolute one. You don't seem to be using ASP.NET nor do you have a relative path, so you can just remove it and feed the path directly to the `DirectoryInfo` constructor.

Comment: What purpose do `PageSize` and  `Page` have when all you want is the latest write time?

Comment: Ok - If I'm doing what you said correctly (probably not!!) I now get - Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers

Comment: Sorry the pagesize stuff is just a leftover from the example i found

Comment: _"That causes another error - Expression is of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo', which is not a collection type"_ - Try adding a line continuation character (an underscore) after the loop: `For Each TXTFile As System.IO.FileInfo In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("\\10.179.221.125\cmsdata\GNH3D\TDD\TDD_waveradar\H1d3\") _`. Alternatively you might have to place `.GetFileSystemInfos` and the rest at the same line for the compiler to detect it as the same statement.

Comment: That has compiled fine and runs but I think the problem I now have is the shear number of files within the structure as it is still running and not got to the msgbox bit!

Comment: I did work after a while though - many thanks!

Comment: Glad we could help! I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo as there was nothing technically wrong with your code.